# Python IF conditions

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I'm new to django python so the if makes me feel confused. Please help me!

Im trying to make a IF condition for Facebook chat bot API. The whole function is when a user sends something in the Facebook chat, my bot will remove all punctuations, lower case the text and split it based on space. 
After that he will pick a joke from json list with the keyword he got. A quick reply with 2 buttons "Yes" and "No" is also sent to user with the joke.

It also checks if the keyword is absent. Now I want that when user types "No" in the chat, my bot will send something back like "Then not". What did I do wrong here?

```
strong texttokens = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", ' ', recevied_message).lower().split()
joke_text = ''
for token in tokens:
    if token in jokes:
        joke_text = random.choice(jokes[token])

        .... some code

        send_message(fbid, joke_text)

        quick_text = "Do you want another joke? "
        send_quick_reply_message(fbid, quick_text)
        break
if not joke_text:
    joke_text = "I didn't understand! " \
                "Send 'stupid', 'fat', 'dumb' for a Yo Mama joke!"
    send_message(fbid, joke_text)
    if 'No':
        joke_text = "Then not"
        send_message(fbid, joke_text)
```

Comment: wrong indentation level on the last `if`? it is executed only if `not joke_text`

Comment: When I put the last if to the begin, bot will send both if statements ( not joke_text and last if ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if 'No':
```

is always true, you probably want to be checking if something == 'No'?

Comment: Good point! I have tried to put [if recevied_message == 'No':] on that before but it still sent "I didn't understand..." of the above if back

Comment: Oke I realize that I am a noob. I just can switch the position of the if received_message == 'No': before the other if. It worked for me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code have a problem

```
 if 'No':
    joke_text = "Then not"
    send_message(fbid, joke_text)
```

What is 'No"? You have to compare something with "No".
And also this  `if` condition is on wrong indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

'No' is a string.

```
if 'No'
```

always return True.